# Caching configuration in ZF2 & Doctrine 2

Tags: caching, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zfdoctrine

I try to build a simple application using **Zend Framework 2** and **Doctrine 2**. I decided to use YAML config files so my `doctrine.yml` file is as follow:

```
driver:
    application_entities:
        class: 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver'
        cache: 'array'
        paths:
            - '__DIR__/../src/__NAMESPACE__/Entity'
    orm_default:
        drivers:
            'Application\Entity': application_entities
    authentication:
        orm_default:
            object_manager: 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'
            identity_class: 'Application\Entity\User'
            identity_property: 'login'
            credential_property: 'password'
configuration:
    orm_default:
        metadata_cache: 'array'
        query_cache: 'array'
```

Now, the question is: is my cache config proper? And how can I verify it's actually working?

Of course I know I should use some better driver than simple array but for the moment it's enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Doctrine** provides a set of command-line tools to simplify common administration tasks such this. Here is an example list of available commands:

[image: Doctrine Console Commands]

In your case, you should use **[orm:ensure-production-settings](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php#L382-395)** command to make sure that Proxy Generation, Metadata and Query cache configurations are correct.

Assuming that you are using [DoctrineORMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule) to integrate **doctrine** with **zend framework 2**, open the console and simply type:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/projectroot
$ php public/index.php orm:ensure-production-settings
```

The output will warn you if the caching configuration is incorrect.

Here is the detailed [official documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html) for doctrine console.